# How to collect and merge different objects in Java Stream in proper order?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two objects:

```
String y = "Y"
String r = "R"
```

how to collect and merge this values with Java Stream to receive this line:
`"YYRYYRYYRYY"` ?

The stream can be endless, but should start with `YY` and end with `YY`, but each third value should be `R`

Comment: Streams aren't helpful to that task. Forget about them. Add the elements you want to a StringBuilder (or concatenate them directly with the + operator in one expression, really)

Answer (score 2):

### Finite sequence

Supposed you want to create a finite sequence of characters containing `Y` or `R`, **randomly**, just create some `next()` method and call it repeatedly:

```
public final class SequenceGenerator {
    private final String[] elements;
    private final Random rnd;

    public SequenceGenerator(Collection<String> elements) {
        this.elements = elements.toArray(new String[elements.size()]);
        rnd = new Random();
    }

    public String next() {
        return elements[rnd.nextInt(elements.length)];
    }

    public String generate(int amountOfElements) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfElements; i++) {
            sb.append(next());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The class takes the collection of possible elements to draw from and its `next` methods chooses one randomly. The `generate` method calls it repeatedly and appends the drawn elements.

Usage is simple:

```
SequenceGenerator gen = new SequenceGenerator(List.of("Y", "R"));
System.out.println(gen.generate(11));
```

May print something like:

```
YYRYYRYYRYY
```

---

### Endless stream

You can also nicely use the `Stream` API here to create an endless stream:

```
SequenceGenerator gen = new SequenceGenerator(List.of("Y", "R"));
Stream<String> sequence = Stream.generate(gen::next);
```

---

### Edit: `YY` and `R`

As you said you want the stream to start and end with `YY`, as well as have a `R` at every third position, we need to modify `next()` a bit. First of all we add a field `int amount` to keep track of calls. Then `next()` is modified to account for `YY` at the start and `R`. Likewise `generate` must be modified to account for `YY` at the end. The Stream-variant can remain unchanged since it uses the modified `next()` and doesn't need to account for `YY` at the end since it is endless.

```
public final class SequenceGenerator {
    // ...
    private int amount;

    public SequenceGenerator(Collection<String> elements) {
        // ...
        amount = 0;
    }

    public String next() {
        // Start must be 'YY'
        if (amount == 0 || amount == 1) {
            amount++;
            return "Y";
        }

        // Every third must be 'R'
        if (amount % 3 == 0) {
            amount++;
            return "R";
        }

        // Pick a random element
        amount++;
        return elements[rnd.nextInt(elements.length)];
    }

    public String generate(int amountOfElements) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfElements - 2; i++) {
            sb.append(next());
        }

        // End must be 'YY'
        sb.append("YY");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Actually there is another requirement we need to account for. The concatenation of `YY` at the end must be valid in regards to the rule that forces a `R` at each third position. So for `generate` the `amountOfElements` must be two bigger than a value which is dividable by `3`, else the resulting value is invalid.

And we need to account for edge cases, `amountOfElements` must be at least `5`, every smaller sequence is not valid. `YYRYY` is the first valid sequence. The modified method:

```
public String generate(int amountOfElements) {
    if (amountOfElements < 5 || (amountOfElements - 2) % 3 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid sequence length");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: well, looks like no better solution, than to generate and merge all that with old-style for loop

Comment: @Igor Well, I showed you the Stream-approach. It only uses the `next` method which is pretty lightweight, no loops at all. Remove the `generate` method and use `Stream.generate(gen::next)`. Then you have an endless stream.

Comment: Why not `amountOfElements % 3 != 2`?

Answer (score 1):

If yor want to use a stream, you have to do something like this:

```
final long iterateLimit = 20;
final String sequence = "YYR";
final String suffix = "YY";
final String yyrString = Stream.generate(() -> sequence)
                               .limit(iterateLimit)
                               .collect(Collectors.joining())
                               .concat(suffix);
```

I offer generate *sequence* of "**YYR**" and add *suffix* "**YY**" after creating the string.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a contradiction in your requirement “The stream can be endless, but should … end with YY”.

From what I can see, you want just a repeating stream of `Y`, `Y`, `R`, which can be constructed like

```
String y = "Y";
String r = "R";
String[] toRepeat = { y, y, r };
Stream.generate(() -> toRepeat).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
```

so you could print this endless sequence:

```
Stream.generate(() -> toRepeat).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

To turn it into a finite sequence that ends with “yy”, use a limit which is one less than a number divisible by three, e.g. five, eight, eleven, 332, etc.

Then, you may collect/merge the stream into a `String`:

```
String[] toRepeat = { y, y, r };
String seq = Stream.generate(() -> toRepeat).flatMap(Arrays::stream)
      .limit(11)
      .collect(Collectors.joining());
System.out.println(seq);
```

Instead of `.collect(Collectors.joining())`, you could also use `.reduce("", String::concat)`, but the former usually is more efficient.

A different approach would be to iterate through all sequences fulfilling your requirement:

```
Stream.iterate(y+y, s -> s+r+y+y)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This could be used to find the n’th valid sequence:

```
Stream.iterate(y+y, s -> s+r+y+y)
    .skip(10)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```